# Delete hotmail account but keep MSN messenger

Tags: email, windows-live-messenger, spam-prevention, hotmail

Is it possible to delete hotmail account but keep MSN messenger. My hotmail account got hacked into sending spam and I'm just fed up. I want to get rid of the email account but unfortunately I do use msn messenger. What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to have a hotmail account to use MSN messenger. I don't. The problem however is that you need to change the e-mail associated with your account.

You could go to live.com and log in. There on the right side, you'll see your username. Move mouse over it and option Account will show up. There in the bottom part of the page, you'll see other options and in that area "your e-mail addresses". Click there and change the address to another address.

This should allow you to move to a new address and keep your MSN contacts with no intervention on their side (or at least it did for me few years ago).

Comment: I went into options, all that does is add an email associated with your account. It's not really change your MSN messenger email.

Comment: @erotsppa Shouldn't there be a change option next to existing e-mail? You can use it to select another e-mail address. Then you can remove the existing one.

Comment: Are you referring to "Add email addresses to your account so you can read all of your email in Hotmail and receive notifications at the email address you choose." ? I can't find a way to change my Windows Live ID, which is what I use to log into MSN messenger

Comment: @erotsppa Yes, that. Using that, you should be able to change the e-mail address associated with the Windows Live ID.

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure that the spam is really physically coming from your account ?

A spammer has no need to hack your account in order to send email that seems to have come from you. This is actually quite easy to do, and all he really needs to know (or guess) is that your account exists. The spam email could originate from anywhere in the world, and not just from your account, but is faked to look as if you have sent it.

So if you do not see the spam in your sent-mail folder, there is no reason to think that your account was hacked. Changing your password to something long and complex should be enough as a security measure.

I would also do some antivirus scans by several antivirus products to ensure that you are not infected with a keylogger type of virus. With this kind of a virus installed, all your transactions and passwords may be compromised. Ensure also that your bank-account is insured, if you do buy online.

Comment: I see the spam in my sent folder.

Comment: Changing your password is probably enough to fix the hotmail problem. The hotmail servers themselves are not (probably) infected. In your place I would be much more concerned about my own computer being infected. See [What to do if my computer is infected by a virus or a malware?](http://superuser.com/questions/100360/what-to-do-if-my-computer-is-infected-by-a-virus-or-a-malware).